# nodejs bodyParser.json convert float number

Tags: node.js

My request postman request

```
{
    "data":{
        "hoauBagId":"WEB20180904003",
        "battery":null,
        "incoterm":30.0,
    }
}
```

But when I do console req.body

```
{ data:
   { hoauBagId: 'WEB20180904003',
     battery: null,
     incoterm: 30,
   }
}
```

I know the problem because I use "app.use(bodyParser.json());" and it convert my number
How can I get 30.0 instead of 30?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to float parseFloat() explicitly.
I think this happens only because 30.0 = 30! Please try with 30.1 I think should be satisfied with your result

Answer (score 0):

You can done this with `parseFloat()`

Lets say you create a function that return a float number like:

```
function pFloat(data) {
   return parseFloat(data);
}
```

Where `data` is a new variable that you create from `response` data like:

```
 const data = data.incoterm
```

or you could simply:

```
 var data = parseFloat(data.incoterm);
```